# How to handle aborted synchronic AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

My web server can change its IP in response to a specific HTTP request.
The thing is, that the browser uses synchronic `$.ajax()` to post this request. Since the server IP is changed the request is aborted once timed-out ("Aborted" in firebug net tab). However, since the post is synchronic, the browser (FF in this case) hangs infinitely. As far as I understand, it is not possible to timeout or programmatically abort sync AJAX.

For many practical reasons, I cant change the request to be async. Any ideas how to handle this situation? Thanks

Comment: Try using `timeout` parameter if you are making a sync `ajax` call. by which you can handle timeout inside `error` callback gracefully.

Comment: Can you let us know what these many practical reasons are?  Your answer won't likely be in a synchronous request.  Perhaps we can help you find another way.  The best way to do this would be get the server to return data before changing IP.

Comment: Does it really hang infinitely? Afaik somewhen a HTTP timeout should occur (based on browser settings) and an exception should be raised which you can catch.

Comment: @Vega `timeout` does not work with sync AJAX.

Comment: @Brad changing to async is theoretically possible, but involves with significant code changes.

Comment: @Bergi Yes. Even after 10 minutes (not exactly infinite, but still...) FF still hangs.

Comment: @Bergi, It's hanging indefinitely, because a connection is established successfully.  There may even be a response header set.  If a connection succeeds, browsers wait a long time.  I'd imagine they would wait until the underlying TCP connection closes, which if TCP keepalive is not enabled, won't happen for a long time.

Comment: @Assaf286294, You have no way to change what is happening server-side?

Comment: @Brad: OK, thanks. So it would close, but it would need a *very* long time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options available to you.

### Change server-side behavior

Change the web application on the server to complete its response to the client before changing its IP address.  Then, your application gets a response whether or not the call succeeded.

### Use async AJAX calls

Self-explanatory.  You don't want to do this, but you really should, and not for just the problem you're having now.  If your application really requires significant changes for this to work, then it probably has other design issues that could be revisited as well.

You're using a fire-and-forget method anyway currently, so I really don't see why this would be a problem.

Comment: I followed you suggestion to use async calls. It wasn't as complicated as I thought. Thanks.